# I'm implementing billing using flutter's in_app_purchase, but I get a family sharing request

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

A request popup to parents will be displayed as shown in the image below.

Then, whether you press "Cancel" or "Ask for Approval", `purchaseDetails.status` will continue to be `PurchaseStatus.pending`, and eternal and circular will continue to rotate.

My smartphone has family sharing turned off.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It has already been answered here!

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/68626